# Abuse of notation or am I missing something

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading a text carefully and I've come across a part that's somewhat confusing.

Suppose there exists a $C^1$ function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and by fixing $x$ and $y$ we define $\phi(t) = F(x+ty)$. My text says that by the fundamental theorem of calculus we can write $$F(x+y) = F(x) + \int_0^1 DF(x+ty)y \ dt$$

How is the operation in the integrand defined if $DF$ maps to something $m$-dimensional and $y$ is $n$-dimensional. I'm being a bit of a stickler but I want to make sure there are no gaps in my understanding.

Comment: $DF(x+ty)$ is some linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $DF(x+ty)y$ is this map applied to the vector $y$, which gives us a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: As is, it sorta looks like multiplication, so maybe it would be easier to understand if it were written a little differently. Would writing it like $DF[x+ty](y)$ or $(DF(x+ty))(y)$ help?  That way you can see that $DF(x+ty)$ is just a function that is acting on the vector $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the derivative of a differentiable map $F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, I denote which by $dF^{x}$, is by definition a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$. A reason that many authors write $DF(x)$ instead of $dF^{x}$ is: a map $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is linear iff there is some $m \times n$ matrix $A$ such that $f(x) = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$; the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is by definition the matrix of $df^{x}$ with respect to the usual bases and is denoted by $Df(x)$; therefore $df^{x}(y) = Df(x)\cdot y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

By chain rule, formally we have $\varphi'(t) = DF(x+ty)y$; hence the map being integrated is in fact the map $t \mapsto DF(x+ty)y: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$, but the map $t \mapsto DF(x+ty)$ carries $[0,1]$ to $\mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{m})$.

I prefer not to use $Df(x)$ to denote the derivative of $f$ at $x$; I reserve it for Jacobian matrix. You are encouraged to check whether the author use $Df(x)$ to mean a map or a matrix; if the former is the case and if you are not yet familiar with that, then you can write $Df(x)(y)$ to remind yourself.

Comment: Can the integration be viewed as integrating every coordinate component of $DF(x+ty)y$?

Comment: Yeah, we can integrate every continuous map $f$ that carries a compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for every $m \geq 1$; if $m \geq 2$, then $\int_{I}f := (\int_{I}f_{1}, \dots, \int_{I}f_{m})$.

Answer (score 1):

For each value $x + ty$, the derivative $DF(x + ty)$ is itself a linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. Hence acting on $y \in \mathbb R^n$,
$$DF(x + ty)y \in \mathbb R^m$$